# How to get vacancy details in blade using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am creating a find work application. In this application people can upload their resume and get invitations from the Employer.
Employers will be uploading their vacancies. So i have 2 types of users here `Employee` and `Employer`. The projects has been almost completed so far but i am struggling at one problem.
Let me explain first the scenario.
i have table in my database as follows: 
`users`

```
id     username
```

===========================================================================
`vacancies`

```
id     vacancy_title      user_id
```

===========================================================================

`resumes`

```
id      resume_title     user_id
```

===========================================================================

When a employee(resume holder) see a vacancy he/she can click on `interested` link. i saving those clicks in a `pivot` table which looks like this:

`user_vacancy`

```
id    user_id       vacancy_id
```

So i have created a `many to many relationship` between users(in pivot table: resume holder)
in this way i am saving the clicks(interested) by resume holder(user). 
So in Employer dashboard i need to show the list of all the clicks(interested) users resume. 
So i have done this so far:

in my controller:

```
public function getListOfclicksResumes()
    {


   $user = User::find(Auth::id());

    $myvacancies = $user->vacancies;
    $users       = [];
    foreach ($myvacancies as $vac):
        foreach ($vac->clickedusers as $emp):
            $users[] = $emp;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

    return view('employer.clicks.index', compact('users'));
}
```

So in above code you can see first i ma getting current user logged in which is Employer. and of course the employer has many vacancies. so i am getting all the vacancies for that current user(Employer) and then getting the `clicked users (resume holders)` and passing that collection to the blade.

Then in Blade:

```
    @foreach($users as $singleUser)
            @foreach($singleUser->resumes as $resume)

//displaying resume holders list here..

            @endforeach  
   @endforeach
```

Now everything is working fine except one thing:

If a Employee clicked on interested link on a 2 vacancies from the same Employer. I will get that user here 2 times. And this is absolutely  fine but then i need to show here on which vacancy this user has clicked. because an employer has many vacancies.

So how i can get that vacancy modal also with the user collection?

I hope my question is clear. if not please ask i will provide more details.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us the relevant `relationship` definitions.

Comment: On `User` model i have :
` public function vacancies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vacancy::class);
    }`

` public function resumes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Resume::class);
    }`

and On `Vacancy` Model i have:

`    public function clickedusers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }`

Comment: One way to do this would be, instead of passing `$users` to your view pass `$user->vacancies` and do the loop in the view. That way you'll have access to `$vac` and `$users`.

Comment: But then this way loop will run as many time how many vacancies are there? i want to run loop only how many clicks(users) are there

Comment: any hope?) anybody?